# Automate Log Shipping Failover

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, log-shipping

Is it possible to automate Log Shipping Failover and Recover Secondary Database in Log Shipping, something in Powershell where it checks for are there any more .trn files to be copied, restore all the unapplied transactions and recover secondary database?

Answer (score 2):

Log shipping is manual failover: you'd use it for "disaster recovery"

You'd use Database Mirroring for automatic fail-over: this is "high availability".

You can [use both though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187016.aspx).

So, no, if you want to achieve this you're using the wrong feature of SQL Server

Comment: Thanks gbn and I know there is no automatic failover in Log SHipping but my requirement is to do log shipping only. I want something in Powershell where it checks for are there any more .trn files to be copied, restore all the unapplied transactions and recover secondary database?

Comment: @Nick: you may not have an unapplied log backup, or you may want to backup/restore the tail of the log manually. Anyway, I haven't done such a thing sorry

Answer (score 0):

Log Shipping Failover

No automated failover. If automatic failover is required, consider Mirroring instead.
To failover:
- Stop the jobs

- Take a tail of the log backup (BACKUP LOG … WITH NO_RECOVERY)
- Apply tail of the log backup to secondary with a RESTORE LOG ... WITH RECOVERY
- If required, configure log shipping in reverse direction
  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191233.aspx)

Allows for rolling patches an upgrades
- Upgrade secondary

- Failover
- Upgrade the original primary (now secondary)

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178117.aspx)